# Space between NetworkImageView and TextView depending on image size

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-xml

I have a `recyclerview` and inside that a `NetworkImageView` and some texts view.

The problem is, depending on the image on `NetworkImageView` the blank space changes.(I notice if image is small no space is added, in the other hand if image is big a bigger blank space is added between image and `textview`.

[image: space]
[image: no space]
So in the first picture it has a big space between image and name/publisher.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="0dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageViewHero" />

            <TableLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TableRow>
                    <TextView
                        android:text="Name"
                        android:paddingRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textViewName"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        />

                </TableRow>

                <TableRow>
                    <TextView
                        android:text="Publisher"
                        android:paddingRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textViewPublisher"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        />

                </TableRow>

            </TableLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

How can I remove this space or add my own (instead of this random thing)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you debug your layout you will probably find out that the NetworkImageView is actually occupying the blank space, but the image ratio doesn't let it fill the entire space. Try adding

```
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

to the NetworkImageView.